# recover project in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, solution

i have 4 project in my solution, framework , domain objects,business objects and website ...
but this morning website project couldnt be loaded... when i tried firsttime to open solution...  "The solution file has been modified outside the enviroment" message seemed and press reload then error is project file is corrupted... how can it happen... how can i fix this...

thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your solution file (.sln) in notepad and check for the consistency of the document. 
The sln file will be in a hierarchical structure (like we have an xml).

You can also open csproj files of different projects that you have in the solution check the xml of the csproj.

Answer (score 1):

One way... if its from some source control , get the latest and leave the changed part by you. 
If you dont have any source control then you can have the two options
 - Create a new solution and add all your projects to it and rebuild it. Check for the errors.
 - If your code is completely corrupted and files are unreadable, that is unrecoverable, 
then you must have to follow this

- copy the projects dlls out of bin
  dir,
- use red gate reflector and extract
  all the class file in new project
  file.
- Now for aspx.cs you can create a new
  project add all aspx file in that new project and also the 
  new cs files generated by the reflector addin. Do it for all pages. When done , right click on Project of web app(if its), then choose convert to web application. Also check the Page header of each page that they are using the same class files.

I know this is little bit tough , but will work....to recover almost that much code, when your app was last compiled.

**Note** : Also you will have to maintain the hierarchy of the project as the reflector add in (FileGenerator on Codeplex) might miss the actual project hierarchy.

Comment: thx amran but there are just around 14 -15 error  entire project... but there is something looks stupid that errors just about scriptmanger or update panel couldnt find but updatepanels and scriptmanagers are already defined in the page...

Comment: see if you are using ajax toolkit, while placing controls they both create asp: as tag prefix. So in designer.cs file check the class of controls you have placed. Whether they are refrencing System.Web.UI or Ajaxtoolkit

Comment: thank you... you are really helpful and by the way iam done with ajax control toolkit... :D